A young girl (around10 i believe) gets hit by a car in front of her brother and falls into a coma
The kids were coming home from school (i think) and they stopped by a store. The girl fought with another for a toy or something, and the other won. Her brother got her another of that thing, but when he got out of the store he saw his sister pass the road without looking and getting hit by a car. She got into a coma, and since they were very close and their parents were going through a divorce, his hair whitened. Some shit happened, but what I remember is this woman putting herself and the boy into comas and getting his sister to confront her fear of that damned car and awakening. 
I've been looking for this movie for years, and i still can's seem to find it. Sorry about my description skill.

Sounds like "The Lazarus Child" from 2005.

A road accident leaves seven-year-old Frankie Heywood gravely injured and deeply comatose, when she is hit by a bus, and her twelve-year-old brother Ben severely depressed and traumatised after he witnessed the event. Their parents, Jack and Alison, have to put aside their fights over their unstable marriage to focus on their damaged children. But as life looks as if it will never improve for the Heywoods, Jack and Alison hear of a controversial medical therapy that could cajole Frankie from her coma. The treatment involves communicating with the comatose patient to coax them back to consciousness and Ben is the key to unlocking Frankie from her sleep.

Here you can see some scenes from movie.
